# javascript function returning undefined but working fine on alert

Tags: javascript, php, function, google-maps, es6-promise

i am using google map api in which there is function where i am passing address and the function returns the latitude and longitude but in this code function returning me undefined , but when i am using alert instead of return it's working fine, please tell me where i am wrong in this code.
i have same problem in past with ajax code but where i use async=false .

```js
<script>
  function GetLocation(address) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
           
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
          
        
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          return longitude;
          //          alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
          // return latitude;
           
                } else {
                  
            return "Request failed.";
                } 
        
            });

        };  
 
 
 var abc = GetLocation(address);

alert(abc);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `geocode()` is an asynchronous call and you can't return something from it. So you need to continue your logic which is depend on results in the callback function.

Or you need to use [**Promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and change some logic to achieve the result. But again with Promises you can't return anything from it. |

In this code you create an return a `Promise` from the function. `Promise` will take **2** functions, one if everything is **OK**, and the second, if something is wrong. If everything is OK, you call it with your **parameter**. On `Promise` you can call `.then()` function and pass into it 2 functions: first will be passed as your `resolve function`, the second as `reject function`. So in this case, when you call `resolve`, it passes the parameter to the first function of `.then()` and you get it there.

```js
function GetLocation(address) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                  
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
             resolve(longitude);
         } else { 
             reject("Request failed.");
         }         
      });
   });    
};
             
var address = 'yourAddress';
GetLocation(address).then(longitude => alert(longitude));
```

**Basic example with Promises**

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  var a = true; // < Here `a` is true, so resolved function is called in `then`
  if(a){
    resolve(a); 
  } else {
    reject('A is not True !');
  }  
}).then(val => alert(val));


new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  var a = false; // < Here `a` is false, so rejected function is called `then`
  if(a){
    resolve(a); 
  } else {
    reject('A is not True !');
  }  
}).then(val => alert(val), err => alert(err));
```